# Pgsql. Returning field as insert result in function

Tags: postgresql

I can return id as an `INSERT` result, like

```
INSERT INTO table(id,field) VALUES($id,$value) RETURNING id;
```

But i cannot return it and assign to variable into my function

```
var = INSERT INTO table(id,field) VALUES($id,$value) RETURNING id;
```

or

```
SELECT INTO var INSERT INTO table(id,field) VALUES($id,$value) RETURNING id;
```

don't work.
How can i do it?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO table(id,field)
VALUES($id,$value)
RETURNING id into var;
```

Comment: If you're using this in a `plpgsql` function, you'll need to [declare](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/plpgsql-declarations.html) the variable first.

Comment: @Wooden Are you sure? Works for me with v9.6.

Comment: I am not using `id` in the column names. It's an auto-increment field and so it will be inserted by the database. In that case, what can I do ?

Comment: @HappyCoder if it's autoincrement you can just return the actual value into the variable:

do $$
declare _var int;
begin
    INSERT INTO foo (field)
    VALUES('test')
    RETURNING id into _var;

    raise notice 'id %', _var;
end
$$

Answer (score 11):

You could also use:

```
var := (INSERT INTO table(id,field) VALUES($id,$value) RETURNING id);
```

Readability is of course a personal preference, but I like this syntax because it shows an obvious assignment.

Comment: what version of postgres do you use. I get syntax error on the statement. I prefer that syntax too.

Comment: @nXqd : That was 2 years ago!  I think I was using PG 9.2.x or so.

Comment: Try it without the colon if it's in the body of a function/proc.